# How to set up a google calendar web hook in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-client

I looked at the google calendar node js api and this wasn’t clear.

How do I set up a web hook using the Nodejs google calendar library?

I want to tell google to ping a server when my clients has either added or changed an appointment on his google calendar?

How can I use Nodejs to set up the watch?

Comment: Have you checked the docs for [push notifications](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/push) ? What wasn't clear.  Did you set up the watch?  What are your issues?

Comment: I don’t know how to set up the watch. The Nodejs library doesn’t have a watch function I don’t think.

Comment: What makes you say that?   Have you tried?  It appears to be part of the library its in the source for event.watch [v3.ts#L6710](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/main/src/apis/calendar/v3.ts#L6710)   Can i see the code you tried?

Answer (score 2):

The Google Calendar API provides [push notifications](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/push) that let you watch for changes to resources (Webhooks).

| Google Calendar Push notification | [<kbd>View in Fusebit [image]</kbd>](https://api.us-west-1.on.fusebit.io/v1/run/sub-c2eaf0578e7140ca/share/share/edit?integrationId=so-71018001) |
| --- | --- |

```js
const calendar = googleClient.calendar('v3');
const watchResponse = await calendar.events.watch({
  resource: {
      id: uuidv4(),
      type: 'web_hook',
      address: 'Your webhook address here'
    },
    calendarId: 'primary'
  });
  
const { data } = watchResponse;
console.log('Calendar Webhook created', data);
```

Comment: Hi, if I want to authenticate with a refresh token, how do I do that? Can I use oauth2Client/

Comment: Hi Chris, you can use a refresh token using oauth2Client.setCredentials({
  refresh_token: `STORED_REFRESH_TOKEN`
});
Read more about it here https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client#handling-refresh-tokens

Comment: Thank you so much that really helped.